# Installing Django 1.9 on IIS8

Tags: fastcgi, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, django-1.9

Does anyone know a guide on how to configure a Django project (django 1.9) to IIS 8.5 on a Windows server 2012R2?

I previously had projects working on IIS 8.5 using django 1.8, but we decided to move on to 1.9 and now all I get are HTTP Error 500.0 Internal Server Error.

The tutorial I followed for django 1.8 is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXbfHtAvubc) with the following variables for FastCGI:

- Name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Value: FooBar.settings
- Name: PYTHONPATH Value: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\FooBar
- Name: WSGI_Handler Value: django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()

[image: Error]

I also followed this [tutorial](http://chrisberragan.com/articles/2014-03-19-installing-django-on-iis-7-5/) and I get a similar error.

Is there an alternative to FastCGI?
Is FastCGI obsolete for django 1.9?
What else can I try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get IIS work with Django 1.9 by not doing a virtualenv.

The video tutorial I posted seems to only work if you do not use a virtualenv.

I tried different methods of making fastCGI work with a virtualenv, but it looks like the python linked to virtualenv is the same one where fastcgi was installed.